# Why the Date is different when accessed througth Domain class and from DB

Tags: grails, groovy, yui, yui-datatable

I have domain class and had a property DOB of type Date and when i access it through domain class object it showing +1 to the actual date in DB. i am displaying all of my data in yui datatable.

I dont know the exact reason for it.Please can u give the reason for it

Comment: You need to provide us with slightly more details, what DB for example.

Comment: voting to close, level of detail is woefully inadequate

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this issue is because of Timezones. Especially if you save your date with time 00:00:00.

Can you play with timezones, and, which is preferable, to store dates only in specified timezone (GST) and, on read, translate to user current Timezone.